# Added Category and got 35 linker errors

Tags: iphone, ios, linker-errors, objective-c-category

I've run into an issue with linker errors that I can't seem to solve or find the reason for problem. I added a `Category` to my iOS project, called `ParentViewController+CoreData`. I didn't add anything to this category in either the `.h` or `.m` file, but if I import it into another file I get 35 linker errors. `ParentViewController` is a view controller in my code that I would like to make a category for. If I make a category from a standard view controller, I have no issues. I've made categories from custom view controllers in the past with no issue, and I can't find the issue here.

Below are the linker errors:

```
Ld /Users/Heather/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lodge-dffwatcyrvyekkdhbejusjleqkjn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Lodge.app/Lodge normal i386
    cd /Users/Heather/Documents/lodge
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -L/Users/Heather/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lodge-dffwatcyrvyekkdhbejusjleqkjn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/Heather/Documents/lodge -F/Users/Heather/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lodge-dffwatcyrvyekkdhbejusjleqkjn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Heather/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lodge-dffwatcyrvyekkdhbejusjleqkjn/Build/Intermediates/Lodge.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Lodge.build/Objects-normal/i386/Lodge.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -all_load -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.1 -framework CoreData -lz -framework CoreGraphics -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CFNetwork -framework QuickLook -framework CoreLocation -framework MessageUI -framework ImageIO -lxml2 -framework CoreText -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lFlurryAnalytics -o /Users/Heather/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Lodge-dffwatcyrvyekkdhbejusjleqkjn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Lodge.app/Lodge

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_kGTMHTTPFetcherErrorChallengeKey", referenced from:
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
  "_kGTMHTTPFetcherErrorDomain", referenced from:
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher failToBeginFetchWithError:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher backgroundFetchExpired] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher uploadNextChunkWithOffset:fetcherProperties:] in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher failToBeginFetchWithError:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher backgroundFetchExpired] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher uploadNextChunkWithOffset:fetcherProperties:] in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o
  "_kGTMHTTPFetcherRetryDelayStartedNotification", referenced from:
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher primeRetryTimerWithNewTimeInterval:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
  "_kGTMHTTPFetcherRetryDelayStoppedNotification", referenced from:
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher destroyRetryTimer] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
  "_kGTMHTTPFetcherStartedNotification", referenced from:
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher beginFetchMayDelay:mayAuthorize:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
  "_kGTMHTTPFetcherStatusDataKey", referenced from:
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher shouldRetryNowForStatus:error:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
  "_kGTMHTTPFetcherStatusDomain", referenced from:
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connection:didReceiveData:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher isRetryError:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher shouldRetryNowForStatus:error:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher chunkFetcher:finishedWithData:error:] in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher chunkFetcher:willRetry:forError:] in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o
      ...
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connection:didReceiveData:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher isRetryError:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher shouldRetryNowForStatus:error:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher chunkFetcher:finishedWithData:error:] in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher chunkFetcher:willRetry:forError:] in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o
      ...
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connection:didReceiveData:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher isRetryError:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher shouldRetryNowForStatus:error:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher chunkFetcher:finishedWithData:error:] in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher chunkFetcher:willRetry:forError:] in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o
      ...
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connection:didReceiveData:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher isRetryError:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher shouldRetryNowForStatus:error:] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher chunkFetcher:finishedWithData:error:] in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o
      -[GTMHTTPUploadFetcher chunkFetcher:willRetry:forError:] in GTMHTTPUploadFetcher.o
      ...
  "_kGTMHTTPFetcherStoppedNotification", referenced from:
      -[GTMHTTPFetcher sendStopNotificationIfNeeded] in GTMHTTPFetcher.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2AccessTokenRefreshed", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication auth:finishedRefreshWithFetcher:error:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2ErrorDomain", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication authorizeRequestImmediateArgs:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
      -[GTMOAuth2SignIn windowWasClosed] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
      -[GTMOAuth2SignIn handleCallbackReached] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication authorizeRequestImmediateArgs:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
      -[GTMOAuth2SignIn windowWasClosed] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
      -[GTMOAuth2SignIn handleCallbackReached] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2ErrorJSONKey", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication tokenFetcher:finishedWithData:error:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2ErrorMessageKey", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2SignIn handleCallbackReached] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2ErrorRequestKey", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication authorizeRequestImmediateArgs:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2FetchStarted", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication notifyFetchIsRunning:fetcher:type:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2FetchStopped", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication notifyFetchIsRunning:fetcher:type:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2FetchTypeAssertion", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication beginTokenFetchWithDelegate:didFinishSelector:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2FetchTypeKey", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication notifyFetchIsRunning:fetcher:type:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2FetchTypeRefresh", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication beginTokenFetchWithDelegate:didFinishSelector:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2FetchTypeToken", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication beginTokenFetchWithDelegate:didFinishSelector:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2FetchTypeUserInfo", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2SignIn fetchGoogleUserInfo] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2FetcherKey", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication notifyFetchIsRunning:fetcher:type:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2KeychainErrorDomain", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain passwordForService:account:error:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain removePasswordForService:account:error:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
      -[GTMOAuth2Keychain setPassword:forService:accessibility:account:error:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2NetworkFound", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2SignIn reachabilityTarget:changedFlags:] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2NetworkLost", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2SignIn reachabilityTimerFired:] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2RefreshTokenChanged", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2Authentication setKeysForResponseDictionary:] in GTMOAuth2Authentication.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2ServiceProviderGoogle", referenced from:
      +[GTMOAuth2SignIn standardGoogleAuthenticationForScope:clientID:clientSecret:] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
      -[GTMOAuth2SignIn auth:finishedWithFetcher:error:] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
      +[GTMOAuth2SignIn revokeTokenForGoogleAuthentication:] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
      +[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:clientID:clientSecret:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
      +[GTMOAuth2SignIn standardGoogleAuthenticationForScope:clientID:clientSecret:] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
      -[GTMOAuth2SignIn auth:finishedWithFetcher:error:] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
      +[GTMOAuth2SignIn revokeTokenForGoogleAuthentication:] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
      +[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:clientID:clientSecret:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2UserSignedIn", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2SignIn handleCallbackReached] in GTMOAuth2SignIn.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2WebViewCancelled", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch viewWillDisappear:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2WebViewFailed", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch webView:didFailLoadWithError:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2WebViewFinished", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch webViewDidFinishLoad:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2WebViewKey", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch notifyWithName:webView:kind:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2WebViewStartedLoading", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch notifyWithName:webView:kind:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
      -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch webViewDidStartLoad:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2WebViewStopKindKey", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch notifyWithName:webView:kind:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
  "_kGTMOAuth2WebViewStoppedLoading", referenced from:
      -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch viewWillDisappear:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
      -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch webViewDidFinishLoad:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
      -[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch webView:didFailLoadWithError:] in GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Do share you .m and .h file

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. My problem was related to the Prefix.pch file where I was creating an endless loop of imports. I instead removed my datasource that was using the Google Drive API and only imported in the specific file that used it. Rookie mistake and was a pain in the butt to figure out, but make sure you also aren't having an endless loop!

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from the file that object file is not read / get by the compiler. Check for the target, if your category file is added to the application target.

This kind of issue I faced a lot, I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: The file is getting added to the application target - I checked in Target->Build Phases->Compile Sources, and ParentViewController+CoreData.m is in there.

Comment: can you mail me your project? But I can reply only after 12hrs, because its night here..time to sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

The project target is compiled with but not linking to the sources for the GTM OAuth 2 controllers, http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/

Comment: It was working fine until I tried to add the category, which doesn't even use those files...any idea why it would cause those errors?